# How do I change my filter then copying all data shown

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet with lots of data in table form. Here's the macro recording for what  want to do

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$2735").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "2015-05-28"
    Range("A2618").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
```

The problem I'm having with this is that it gives specific cell's for the autofilter range (I want to apply this to different table's which may have a different number of rows/columns)

I also want to just select the top left cell once the data is filtered, this code does it by naming it. After that I want to select all the data in the table and copy it. I know this has something to do with Range("A1").CurrentRegion, but I dont know how to implement this.

Another problem I'm having with my code is filtering the results with dates in relation to todays date. For example I want to filter to yesterdays date, then to dates 3 days ago, then last weeks dates.

Sorry this is 3 questions in a post but help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

VBA knows tables as listobjects, so if you want to refer a table in a sheet you can use: `Sheets(i).ListObjects(1).Range`

To select the whole table after filtering: `Sheets(i).ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select`

Setting filter to yesterday: `Sheets(i).ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=format(date()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: Thanks this has helped alot! I have another question though :)
How do I add more dates onto the filter that is set to yesterday, would it be :
criteria:=format(date()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")(date()-2"yyyy-mm-dd") etc?

What im trying to ask is how to format the code so i can make it filter yesterday, then yesterday+2 days before that, then the past week.

Comment: What "then" means for you? Show so the hour listed values at the same time ( look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18135388/4721734) or do you want macro to change from one to another (in this case store your values in an array as in the previous link and loop through them with `for`)